# Multiple Call Recording

Tags: android, call, audio-recording

I am trying to record separately and simultaneously from two phone call sources. Here is the code I am using

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    StopRecording(recorder1);
                    StopRecording(recorder2);                   
              break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    StartRecording_DownLink();
                    StartRecording_UpLink();
              break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              break;
            }
          }
        };
        telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);



public void StartRecording_UpLink(){
         recorder1 = new MediaRecorder();

         recorder1.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);
         recorder1.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
         recorder1.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
         recorder1.setOutputFile(getFilename(AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER_UPLINK));


         recorder1.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
         recorder1.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

         try{
             recorder1.prepare();
             recorder1.start();
         }catch (IllegalStateException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
         }

    public void StartRecording_DownLink(){
         recorder2 = new MediaRecorder();

         recorder2.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
         recorder2.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
         recorder2.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
         recorder2.setOutputFile(getFilename(AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER_DOWNLINK));


         recorder2.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
         recorder2.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

         try{
             recorder2.prepare();
             recorder2.start();
         }catch (IllegalStateException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
         }
```

Once again to be clear, i want to record from up link and down link at the same time when I am calling/called. This program only records the up link. It pops an error when calling the down link recording method. Help please .

Comment: Multiple recorders at once are typically not allowed. Some phones do allow multiple recorders that use _the same AudioSource_ (by using some sort of stream splitter that sends the same data to all clients). To record both the uplink and downlink you should use the `VOICE_CALL` AudioSource. If that doesn't work on your device I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: I am sorry I was not very explicit. I need two separate files for up link and down link. I will need them for further parsing to make a call transcription log.

Comment: I doubt that there's any way to specify that (at least in a way that will work across most devices). Even if you record in stereo, the uplink and downlink are likely to be mixed because otherwise the recording would sound weird when played back, especially if you listen to it using headphones.